# WordPress: Showing posts by categories/tags on the index page

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to show posts by categories/tags on the index page instead of taking the user to the tag.php and category.php pages?

For example, when the user clicks the 'Uncategorized' category, I would like all the Uncategorized posts to replace the list of posts already there on the index page.

I've been trying to find out if anyone has done this but I've had no luck. I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me a link to somewhere that tells me how to go about doing this or lets me know how to change the code to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done.  I can not recall a page that has done it but I do know it would require you creating your own custom page template.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates is a good place to start learning how the page templates are created.

Some additional links
http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/tag-archive-from-a-single-category-is-this-possible?replies=34